# Why my state on my redux toolkit reset itself to the old state?

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Currently I'am working on my authentication flow of react native navigation. Right now I'am already done setup my state management and the login module part. Now the problem is when I console log my state of isLoggedIn of true itself the true value turns to false, Which is I don't understand why the value that I set to the state change back to false.

Question: Why my state isLoggedIn true turns back to false value?

Goal: If I console log the state isLoggeIn the set value may not turn to false, because I am already authenticated.

React Navigation Version: 5

Here is my Navigation:

```
const Navigation = () => {
    
    const {isLoggedIn, isLoading} = useSelector(state => state.user)
    
    console.log(isLoggedIn,"isLoggeIn")

    return (
        <NavigationContainer>

            {
                isLoggedIn ? (
                    <UnauthenticatedUser />
                ) : (
                    <AuthenticatedUser />
                )
            }
           

        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

Here is the logs details:

[image: Logs Illustration]

Comment: can you show where you set the state?

Comment: Check which action is being called that is setting the state back to false, and where it's being called.